# jQuery - Variable Scope Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have the following javascript:

```
      $.getJSON('/calculate_quote/' + moulding_1_id, function(data) {
        moulding_1_cost = data.moulding.cost;
        moulding_1_width = data.moulding.width;
      });
      cost_of_moulding = ( ( 2 * ( width + ( 2 * moulding_1_width ) ) + 2 * ( height + ( 2 * moulding_1_width ) ) ) / 1000 ) * moulding_1_cost;
      $('#item_total').html( cost_of_moulding );
```

The problem is that the two variables `moulding_1_cost` and `moulding_1_width` are undefined outside of the getJSON call.  How do I make these two variables available outside the getJSON call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variables aren't *set* until that callback runs (when the server comes back with the JSON data), so you need to call whatever code uses them from that callback, like this:

```
$.getJSON('/calculate_quote/' + moulding_1_id, function(data) {
  var moulding_1_cost = data.moulding.cost;
  var moulding_1_width = data.moulding.width;
  var cost_of_moulding = ( ( 2 * ( width + ( 2 * moulding_1_width ) ) + 2 * ( height + ( 2 * moulding_1_width ) ) ) / 1000 ) * moulding_1_cost;
  $('#item_total').html( cost_of_moulding );
});
```

Or call another function like this:

```
$.getJSON('/calculate_quote/' + moulding_1_id, function(data) {
  someFunction(data.moulding.cost, data.moulding.width);
});
function someFunction(mqc, m1w) {
  var cost_of_moulding = ( ( 2 * ( width + ( 2 * m1w) ) + 2 * ( height + ( 2 * m1w) ) ) / 1000 ) * m1c;
  $('#item_total').html( cost_of_moulding );
}
```

In either case what remains true is you need to trigger whatever uses the data *once you have the data*, all asynchronous operations are like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing everything inside the getJSON call to ensure that it happens in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Infact they are not undefined (after the code was executed). By skipping the `var` keyword those names go directly into the global scope (which in most instances.. is `window`). So you can access `window.moulding_1_cost` from anywhere of your script once this piece of script has executed.

And that most likely is your problem here, timing. Since this is the success handler of an `ajax request` this code runs asynchronously and therefore, is not executed instantly.

To solve this it's a good practice to use a callback function on your own. Nick Craver's answer has a pretty good demonstration on this.

Comment: ..and I'm so curious who is downvoting this without a reason.

Comment: Not my downvote, but they are in fact completely `undefined` unless something created and initialized them earlier, they're not defined at all until that callback runs at least once.

Answer (score -2):

add

```
var moulding_1_cost;
var moulding_1_width;
```

outside of any javaScript function ;)

Comment: This will cause a problem because the math after the `$.getJSON` will be executed before the callback.